# Node.js writeFile [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I can't get writeFile to write file. It works find if it's not in a function so it's not the module but when the function is called, it results in an error.

> [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined]

JS Code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var input = document.getElementById('filename');
var fileName = input.value;

function recordToFilename() {
var input = document.getElementById('filename');
var fileName = input.value;
var qw = fileName;

if (qw) {
    alert('value of: ' + qw);
    console.log(qw);
    // demo output
    var myObject = {
        qw: qw,
        fullN: function() {
            return this.qw;
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObject.fullN();
    var path = "danny.txt";
    var data1 = "jdsfhadj"
    fs.writeFile(path,data1)
    //end demo output code
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a filename!');
        input.focus();
    }
};
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>writeFile</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bonescript.js"></script>
    <script src="test_3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="filename">Filename</label>
    <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">

    <a id="enter_button" onclick="recordToFilename();"    href="javascript:void(0);" title="enter">enter name</a>
    <br>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `window.fs.writeFile(path,data1)` in your function.

Comment: Are you using browserify or a similar tool to get `require()` and other node functionality in the browser? If so, which one? It may be that `fs.writeFile()` doesn't exist because it's typically not allowed in browsers the way it works in real node.js?

Comment: Requiring the fs module in a browser environment won't work. It returns undefined. The fs module works only if you execute your code on the server

Comment: I'm using cloud 9 ide. and i tried adding the window. still same error.

Comment: The gist of what i'm trying to do is give the user a way to name & start a new text file that will have data provided by another function. If anyone has a better idea please steer me that way.  
the application is in a embedded device (beagleboneblack) so it will allways run localy not exposed to the internet so security is not an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please upgrade your node version to resolve this issue.